# Doing a "qrsh" inside python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to do a "qrsh" which is a grid command which returns a terminal from pool of machines, its behavior is very similar to "rsh", I am trying to run it from inside a python script and came up with following :

```
os.execl("/remote/sge1/default/bin/lx-amd64/qrsh", "-P test")
```

Is it possible to achieve this ? My expectation of output is this :

```
./script.py
(does qrsh and returns terminal) machine>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `os.execl` is slightly tricky.  You are apparently looking for

```
 os.execl("/remote/sge1/default/bin/lx-amd64/qrsh", "qrsh", "-P", "test")
```

However, if you want to actually retain control of the subprocess, the `execl` is wrong - it will *replace* your Python process with the `qrsh` process.  Overall, [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is both easier to use and more versatile. (In fact, unless you are implementing a replacement for `subprocess.call` you should probably stay away from the low-level `os.exec*` primitives.)

```
subprocess.call(['qrsh', '-P', 'test'])
# Look, your Python program is still executing after qrsh finishes!
```

(I am assuming you have `/remote/sge1/default/bin/lx-amd64` in your `PATH` already; if you don't, you need to supply an explicit path to `qrsh` just like in your `execl` call.)

A common beginner mistake is to expect Python (or some other unspecified part of the OS) to parse commands from strings.  Both `execl` and `subprocess` require you to split the command into a list of strings.  At the command line, your shell takes care of this (so "qrsh -P test" gets parsed into `['qrsh', '-P', 'test']` and then passed to `execvp` in this form).

<sup>The `subprocess` module allows you to use `shell=True` to explicitly invoke a shell for this purpose, but you're better off ignoring that, at least until you have a better understanding of the topic; and once you do, you won't want to.</sup>

On Unix, the value of "argument 0" is a curiosity which you probably don't need to worry about.  For example, a login shell gets called as `execvp("/bin/sh", "-sh", ...)` whereas a non-login shell gets invoked as `execvp("/bin/sh", "sh", ....)`.  Most places, argument zero will be identical to the path the actual binary.

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess I missed proper splitting of parameters.